# Nestjs is not getting dotenv value from ConfigModule

Tags: nestjs, dotenv

[envFilePath](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-env-file-path) setting for [configuration](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#configuration) in Nestjs is not working for me. Even I remove `.env` from it. `.env` is still loaded, not `.evn.development`.

Is it because I am using [ConfigService](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-the-configservice)? There is no mentioning about any contradiction.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            envFilePath: ['.env.development', '.env'],
        });
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: so there's a variable in `.env.development` that is not loaded?

Comment: Yes. they are not. The docs said it should take precedence.

Comment: what if you change the order?

Comment: found the issue. My bad. I'll answer myself

Answer (score 1):

Turned out it's myself.

I have a Strategy where I have some code there causing this issue.

```
import { config } from 'dotenv';

config();
```

Comment: is a problem with the new version of nestjs@config?? because I had this problem with the old version